# C++ Симметричный обход бинарного дерева без рекурсии

Tags: c++, указатели, бинарное-дерево

Добрый день! Есть нерекурсивная функция, которая выполняет симметричный обход дерева. Вместо стека использовал деки.

```
struct BinaryTree {
    int Data;
    BinaryTree* Left;
    BinaryTree* Right;
};

//создание бинарного дерева
void Make_Binary_Tree(BinaryTree** Node, int n) {

    BinaryTree** ptr;  //вспомогательный указатель
    srand(time(NULL) * 1000);

    while (n > 0) {
        ptr = Node;
        while (*ptr != NULL) {
            if ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX < 0.5)
                ptr = &((*ptr)->Left);
            else ptr = &((*ptr)->Right);
        }
        (*ptr) = new BinaryTree();
        cout << "Введите значение ";
        cin >> (*ptr)->Data;
        n--;
    }
}

// функция нерекурсивного обхода
void SymmetricOrder_BinaryTree_Loop(BinaryTree* Node) {
deque <BinaryTree> stack;

    do {
        while (Node != NULL) {

            stack.push_back(*Node);
            Node = Node->Left;
        }

        if (stack.size() > 0) {

            *Node = stack.back();
            stack.pop_back(); 
            printf("%3ld", Node->Data);
            Node = Node->Right;
        }
    } while (stack.size() > 0);
}

int main() {

    struct BinaryTree *nodes = { 0 } ;
    struct BinaryTree *root = nodes;

    Make_Binary_Tree(&root, 8);
    SymmetricOrder_BinaryTree_Loop(root);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что выдаёт ошибку:

> "Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для записи. Node было nullptr."

То есть цикл выходит за пределы дерева и указывает на пустую ячейку. По алгоритму так и должно быть, но видимо как-то по-другому реализовано. Как можно исправить, чтобы работало?

Comment: "Alexander Kagalchuk  Какой смысл этого объявления  struct BinaryTree *nodes = { 0 } ; если переменная nodes не используется?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow пожалуй, никакого. Использовал до этого, забыл убрать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данный цикл

```
    while (Node != NULL) {

        stack.push_back(*Node);
        Node = Node->Left;
    }
```

завершает свою работу, когда `Node` становится равным `NULL`.

Однако в последующем блоке кода предложения с `if`

```
    if (stack.size() > 0) {

        *Node = stack.back();
        ^^^^^
```

вы разыменовываете этот указатель, который равен `NULL`.

В результате программа имеет неопределенное поведение.

Помимо этого имеется также логическая ошибка. Представьте, что корневой узел дерева имеет только правого потомка. Тогда в стек изначально будет занесен только этот корневой узел. В предложении с `if` этот узел будет извлечен из стека

```
    if (stack.size() > 0) {

        *Node = stack.back();
        stack.pop_back(); 
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

В результате стек окажется пустым. И на этом завершится весь внешний цикл

```
do {
   //...
} while (stack.size() > 0);
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

несмотря на то, что корневой узел имеет правого потомка.

Также непонятно, почему вы используете стандартный контейнер `std::deque` в то время, как в стандарте C++ уже определен адаптер контейнера `std::stack`.

Также в стеке незачем хранить сами узлы. Достаточно хранить указатели на них.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как функция вывода дерева может быть реализована.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

struct BinaryTree 
{
    int Data;
    BinaryTree *Left;
    BinaryTree *Right;
};

void Make_Binary_Tree( BinaryTree **Node, size_t n ) 
{
    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( ; n != 0; n--) 
    {
        while ( *Node != nullptr ) 
        {
            if ( std::rand() % 2 == 0 )
            {
                Node = &( *Node )->Left;
            }
            else
            {
                Node = &( *Node )->Right;
            }
        }

        *Node = new BinaryTree();

        std::cout << "Введите значение узла: ";
        std::cin >> ( *Node )->Data;
    }
}

// функция нерекурсивного обхода
void SymmetricOrder_BinaryTree_Loop( const BinaryTree *Node ) 
{
    std::stack<const BinaryTree *> stack;

    while ( Node != nullptr || !stack.empty() )
    {
        while ( Node != nullptr ) 
        {
            stack.push( Node );
            Node = Node->Left;
        }

        std::cout << stack.top()->Data << ' ';
        Node = stack.top()->Right;
        stack.pop();
    }
}

int main() 
{
    BinaryTree *root = nullptr;

    Make_Binary_Tree( &root, 5 );
    SymmetricOrder_BinaryTree_Loop( root );
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом

```
Введите значение узла: 1
Введите значение узла: 2
Введите значение узла: 3
Введите значение узла: 4
Введите значение узла: 5
1 2 5 4 3
```

Этот вывод соответствует следующему представлению дерева

```
1
\
 \
  2
  \
   \
    3
    /
   /
  4
  /
 /
5
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!
Скажите, а в чём отличия работы вашей функции создания дерева от моей? Другими словами почему у вас дерево выстраивается всегда с одним потомком от каждой вершины, кроме корня? Сам увидеть не могу...